# WordPress Send notification when I publish a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, hook

I want to send a notification web push when i publish a CPT named 'Notification' in WordPress.

```
$data = array(
'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'data' => array(
    'foo' => 'bar'
),
'headings' => array(
    'en' => 'Test Notifications API'
),
'contents' => array(
    'en' => 'Test Notifications API'
),
'url' => 'PAGE URL',
'include_player_ids' => [
  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
]);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I want to send $result when i publish my CPT 'Notification'.

Thanks for help.

Comment: you want to send email notification on new post created ?

Comment: No, when i publish a CPT 'Notification', i want to send a Web and Mobile notification.
Actually, this work but i want to set it to only send in case of publish my notification'

Comment: i think you should use firebase api for push notifications. Please also see this hook wp_insert_post https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/

Comment: I use OnePush and i cant use another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook it to some action, for example `save_post` or `transition_post_status` or

```
function my_published_notification( $new, $old, $post ) {
     if ( $new === 'publish' && $new !== $old ) {
           // put whatever you want to do here
     }
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_published_notification', 10, 3 );
```

For CPT you also  have some custom hooks options like like `save_*` or `publish_*` where `*` is `myCPTname`.

```
add_action( 'publish_myCPTname', 'my_published_notification', 10, 2 );
```

See more info ok hooks and actions to get more details.

Comment: Thanks you, i solved it before but thanks to your answer